# Rendered HTML page doesnt load event handlers to all elements

Tags: jquery, node.js, firebase, express, ejs

I am currently developing a project which consists of a web server app in nodejs + express and some client views which are rendered with ejs. In my main app.js we have the following:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const firebase = require('firebase');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');

const config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyC4g2YjCJ9uF5Ea8loYXVm7xinpumjRlfI",
    authDomain: "tic-project-46906.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://tic-project-46906.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "tic-project-46906",
    storageBucket: "tic-project-46906.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "131019956403"
  };
firebase.initializeApp(config);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : false}));
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));

const database = firebase.database();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));

app.set('/views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/views/menu.html'));
});

// select w/o filters
app.get('/movies', (req, res) => {
    var value;
    const movies = []; 
    var keys = [];
    database.ref('movie-list').on('value', snapshot => {    
        snapshot.forEach(element => {
            movies.push(element.val());
            keys.push(element.key);
        });
    });
    res.render("movies.html", {
        data: movies,
        ids : keys
    });
});

// select one element + subchilds
app.get('/movies/:Id', (req, res, next) => {
    var reviews = [];
    database.ref('movie-list').orderByKey().equalTo(req.params.Id).once('value', snapshot => {
        var movie;
        snapshot.forEach(element => {
            movie = element.val();
        });

        res.render("movie-item.html", {
            data : reviews
        });
    });
});

// add elem
app.post('/movies/add', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    const newMovieKey = database.ref('movie-list').push().key;
    database.ref('movie-list/' + newMovieKey).set(req.body);
    res.sendStatus(200);
});

// update
app.post('/movies/edit/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('update-called');

    database.ref('movie-list').orderByKey().equalTo(req.params.id).once('value', snapshot => {
        console.log(req.params.id);
        //database.ref('movie-list/' + req.params.id).update(req.body);
    });
});

// delete
app.delete('/movies/delete/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('delete called');
    console.log(req.params.id);
    database.ref('/movie-list/' + req.params.id).remove();
    res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log("Deschis pe portul 8080");
});
```

Now the problem is, every time I am trying to load my elements' handlers in javascript, there's only the first one that gets to work. Since I need the functions to work for every element I am loading via the response I get from the server, I can only update and delete the last element added. I am using ajax to send requests to server.

So if I am pressing on either edit input or delete anchor it won't budge.

Here is the HTML page content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Proiect TIC - Buruleanu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="main-body">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="media/logo2.png" width="140px" height="120px">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="search-bar">
                Search by movie title...
            </div>
            <h2>MOVIES LIST</h2>
            <hr>
            <h4>The main sets for this week:</h4>
            <div class="content-section">
                <ul class="movies-list">
                    <% for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) { %>
                        <li class='list-item'>
                            <div class='item-content'>
                                <div class='item-poster'>
                                    <img src='<%= data[i].PosterLocation %>' />
                                </div>
                                <div class='item-description'>
                                    <h4>
                                        <%= data[i].Title %>
                                    </h4>
                                    <%= data[i].Description %>
                                </div>
                                <div class='item-ratings'>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <p>IMDB rating:</p>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <h4>
                                                <%= data[i].Rating %>/10
                                            </h4>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <form action="/movies/edit/<%= ids[i] %>" method="post">
                                                <input id='edit-button' type="submit" value="Edit">
                                            </form>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a id='a-del' onclick'deleteFunction()' href='#<%= ids[i] %>'>Delete</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>    
                        </li>
                        <% } %>
                         <div class="review-write-form">
                         <h3>Add or Update a movie</h3>
                        <form action="/movies/add" method="post">
                          Title: <input type="text" name="Title"><br>
                          Rating: <input type="number" name="Rating"><br>
                          PosterLocation: <input type="text" name="PosterLocation"><br>
                          Description: <input type="text" name="Description"><br>
                          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                        </form>
                        </div>
                </ul>
                </div>
                <footer>
                    Proiect realizat de Buruleanu Ionut-Robert. Grupa 1091 E-business.
                </footer>
            </div>

    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

And the javascript code:

```
    $('document').ready(function() {
                 $('#a-del').click(function() {
                 console.log('we are here!');
                  var id = $('#a-del').attr('href');
                  console.log(id);
                  $.ajax({
                   url: '/movies/delete/' + id.replace('#',''),
                   type: 'DELETE',
                   success: function() {
                     console.log('succes');
                  },
                  error: function() {
                     console.log(error);
                  }
                  });
                });

                function deleteFunction() {
                console.log('we are here!');
                  var id = $('#a-del').attr('href');
                  console.log(id);
                    $.ajax({
                       url: '/movies/delete/' + id.replace('#',''),
                       type: 'DELETE',
                       success: function() {
                         console.log('succes');
                      },
                      error: function() {
                         console.log(error);
                      }
                    });
                };

                $('#edit-button').click(function() {
                    console.log('edit-clicked!');
                });
    });
```

I have tried to force the html elements by indicating onclick function as well as manipulating them via the jquery. Now I dont really understand why aren't all of them sending any output when the event is fired.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You put the same id for the edit button and for the delete button for all the button in the loop.

the jquery function $("#myid") on a id is bind only once.

Use class instead :

```
<button href="yolo" id="a">A</button>
<button href="yala" id="a">A2</button>
$("#a").click(function(){ console.log($("#a").attr("href"))})


// click on the two button always display yolo

 <button href="yolo" class="a">A</button>
 <button href="yala" class="a">A2</button>

 $(".a").click(function(){ console.log($(this).attr("href"))})

 // click display the good values
```